# Cloning And Editing Managed Package Visualforce Pages

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, visualforce-component, custom-field

I have been informed that I can make a COPY of a Visualforce Page inside a Managed Package (Rootstock in this case) and include/exclude fields from the layout in the VF code, then assign my custom copy of the VF page as the default.

The default page from Rootstock is lacking many needed fields, plus we have custom fields that they only expose, through Field Sets, in a tab buried two clicks deep in the layout.

However, I'm running into an error when I try to pursue this approach:

> Error: Unsupported attribute cntr in  in CUSTOM_SalesOrder at line 27, column 139

---

**Original VF Page (header)**

[image]

---

**Original VF Page (version settings)**

[image]

---

When cloning this (I simply copied the source text, created a New VF page, pasted it, then added settings as shown above, but also added the Rootstock package as well), I start getting complaints about missing components.  I presume this is somehow related to the Managed Package status and that somehow when I "clone" the page for editing, I need to do it differently.

**Attempting to create a copy**

[image]

I have unfortunately, during previous attempts at this process, clicked the "create" option next to the error twice, so two components/attributes have now entered the system on my behalf.

---

How do I create/set up a new copy of a `Visualforce Page` included in a `Managed Package?

---

**UPDATE**:   I also tried setting the Salesforce.com version to 26.0 as the original VF points to.  Same error.

Comment: Unless the controller access is Global you will not be able to get the functionality of the page without recreating the controller yourself which is really not an easy task unless you know what's under the hood. While you can clone the page that does not clone the functionality that is underneath.

Comment: Keep a note that if visualforce is using the Visualforce component, you can't use that VF because they will not be global by default. And you can not make it global as they are Managed.

Comment: Interesting.  Our paid "expert" is telling me to do this, but he may have assumed I would know better about the components.  I specifically asked if the page/code would continue to point to the actual behind-the-scenes code, so I could simply alter the VF page (copy) itself, and he said yet, but there may have been a communication faux pas.

Comment: One time I thought I would try to "include" the managed page within a page you created to add around it but alas, the included pages controller needed to be global. Just in case you thought about that route. Save you some time. Not to mention if you could it would not look pretty anyway

Comment: I believed (hoped?) that by including the Rootstock package as one of the Version Settings, that would accomplish that.  Ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There appears to be only two ways to do this:**

*Ask the provider of the Managed package to include your Visualforce page(s) in their package and them push it back to your Org.*

*Ask the provider to make the associated code from the cloned VF page "Global"*

If the provider is intent on keeping things secure and only usable within their product on pages they provide, you are likely out of luck.